# What would be possible if my character was able to manipulate electricity

Tags: science-fiction, physics, super-powers, electricity, electromagnetism

I am outlining and plotting a novel about someone who is able to manipulate electricity (as in electric currents, charges, etc). Sadly, physics isn't my forte so I was wondering what exactly is possible for ny character other than creating sparks and being a walking phone charger (for example, could this lead to manipulating electromagentism or bio-electric currents?)
Thank you for the help!

Comment: there's actually a book series about a group of people with a range of powers based off of electricity, it's the Micheal Vey series. not sure if it's 100% accurate, but it should help you get a general idea, and it's a good read too.

Comment: I, a regular unpowered human, am able to manipulate electricity, and I am pretty certain that so are you. With our ability to manipulate electricity we can, for example, light up the night, communicate with perfect strangers living in countries far far away, or, in the immortal words of Frederick Brooks, make a *"display screen come to life, showing things that never were nor could be"*.

Comment: "Gentlemen, as the unusually evil president of the otherwise quite-dull local electric utility, I propose that we capture and enslave this fellow. This will cause a very slight decrease in our costs, as he will replace only one of our 50 peak-load gas-powered generators. I'm sure that nothing could possibly go wrong, so I will entrust the project to one of my most violent and irresponsible henchmen whom I have inexplicably kept upon our payroll for years."

Comment: 4 answers and no upvotes!  Good enough to answer is good enough to upvote, folks.

Comment: @wilik IMHO good enough to answer is not the same as good enough to upvote. The OP doesn't share any research or analysis, which are hallmarks of good questions. I didn't downvote it; I don't think it's a bad question per say, and the topic is something potentially relevant to others which can justify investing the time to answer it. But the fact that the question is answerable doesn't automatically mean it's deserving of an upvote.

Comment: You would be able to do nasty things to electronics. Killing cell-phones and computers. Doing the same to any modern car.

Comment: Have you read The Power by Naomi Alderman ('Neil Adam Armon')?

Comment: How subtle can this control be? If it's at enough of a low level, muscle impulses are basically electricity, so reflexes could be much higher, for example. Also are we talking about remote controlling electricity? Because with the same principle you can basically kill anyone by stopping their heart. It's unfortunate that most bullets aren't ferro-magnetic (so you can't deflect them with an electro-magnetic field) but maybe this could be a nice setup, where advanced weapons are magnetic and you need an ancient one to kill your character.

Answer (score 6):

If you can arbitrarily manipulate electric charges you do a lot more than make lightning bolts or magnetic fields.

You can manipulate chemical bonds between atoms in molecules. The atoms stay the same, but the molecules can be assembled and disassembled (assuming fine enough control). Things like forcing oxygen to react with otherwise fairly inflammable things, or accelerating, decelerating, stopping chemical reactions (not good for living things).

You could move electrons in such a way so as to produce electromagnetic radiation such as light, microwaves, radio waves, x-rays as well. Lasers are included in this. You could also make plasma.

You could also imbalance the distribution of electrons within an object so that electrostatic forces are exerted on it, and this would not be healthy for the object with which this is being done. Doing so would also be very similar to one of multiple ways the ways you could produce arcs of lightning, except in this case you also use your power to stop the electrons from jumping.

For example, just forcing electrons to jump between two neutral objects would produce lightning but would also result in secondary arcs going back the other way to re-equalize the charge between the two objects. Alternatively imbalancing the electron distribution within a single object towards one side would cause result in bolts jumping to that object. As soon as you released the imbalance, the charge would jump back out.

The only way I can see to suppress secondary arcs is to gradually build up a charge imbalance over time before prior to the (equalizing) arc being produced, or to gradually redistribute the charge after an arc which results in charge imbalance. An extreme form of static management.

And yes, you could manipulate nerve impulses. Having the perception and processing capacity to do some of these things that require fine control would be more impressive than the ability to actually manipulate charges.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine what a person that knows their physics can do if they have access to a great variety of resistors, capacitors, magnets, power generators and wires.

**Your <strike>human Pikachu</strike> super powered character can do the same things, but without the need for such devices.**

Knowledge of physics may help them act like a human Tesla coil or a walking tazer as they wish.

Answer (score 2):

If you want near-plausible science you can imagine someone who has been selectively inoculated with DNA from an electric eel.

With practice, this could allow them to build up and discharge electricity from phone-charger level to fatal shock.  By using their own electricity they could power all sorts of devices to their own advantage in a MacGyverish way.

*Trapped in a workshop by a magnetic door lock he found some copper wire and, winding it round his arm to form a solenoid, he ..."*

The problem you will face all along is your lack of knowledge of how electricity really works. Either you can simply have your hero magically send lightning bolts from his fingers for no apparent reason or you can be more accurate. I don't think there is a halfway house. Of course this depends on who you want to convince - science-fiction in cinema is notorious for getting it ludicrously wrong.

I do however suggest you read up about Nikola Tesla. I'm sure you will get inspiration from some of his experiments.

> A multiple exposure picture of Tesla sitting next to his "magnifying
> transmitter" generating millions of volts. The 7-metre (23 ft) long
> arcs were not part of the normal operation, but only produced for
> effect by rapidly cycling the power switch.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla
>
> [image]

Comment: Not sure I would call "add DNA from X to get its abilities" near-plausible---for a start, the requisite development largely happens in the developing embryo.But its a nice pseudosciencey catchphrase

Comment: Ah yes, who wouldn't love to have a machine that accidentally produces 7-metre-long arcs when you turn it on or off?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not a physics professor or electrical engineer, but I know enough I could try and point you in the right direction.

There are two main types of electricity, AC and DC(yes, like the band). AC is what you have running through your walls and into your outlets. DC is the more (I say more because I'm pretty sure AC doesn't occur naturally, but I might be wrong)natural state, like lightning or when your friend shocks you. This is also the type that actually power most of your devices, like the computer or phone you're probably using. Now you might be thinking, 'but if AC is in the walls, then how did my computer get to DC?'. the answer is simple. If you grab your computer charger and look at the 'brick' in the middle of the cord, it should say something along the lines of

Input- 120 V~1.2A   50-60Hz

Output- 12V 2A

or close to it somewhere. This is the inverter, changing the AC outlet to DC charging power, which is then held in your computer's battery. The reason power is AC in your outlets is because it is safer. getting zapped with AC power(although still dangerous) isn't as painful as DC, and not as dangerous either.

I'm guessing your character is making DC power, which is the more painful type. the first thing you should define is his Voltage and Amperage. These will shape his powers throughout your book. Voltage is how much the electricity can power. More voltage, more pain when he shocks someone, and the brighter he can make lightbulbs. Amperage is how much electricity there is, which is the marginally more dangerous of the two. [You can zap someone with 40000V and they'll be fine](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/the-hacksmith-arduino-controlled-hot-potato/f47c94d5afa046259871cf0b7492f3f3) IF the amperage is low enough. If you zap someone with enough Amps, you can kill them(I'm not sure of the exact limit).

The other factor you have to take into account is where you zap someone, and where the electricity is going. Just poking their arm will hurt, but probably not kill. If the electricity is traveling across their body through their heart, then it can really hurt. Electricity is always trying to find the quickest path to ground, which will be the main factor in your damages you do to another human. if they are well insulated(rubber boots and dry) then they won't feel as much if they were standing in a puddle. BUT if your character can also act as a ground without hurting himself, then all he needs is to touch the person in two places(they don't need to be very far apart, maybe just two fingers) and then the electricity can get to ground, zapping the person.

Another thing I'd like to mention is that your character probably won't be playing Zeus and throwing lightning bolts at everyone who dares stand in his way. Lightning is millions(Again, I don't know the exact number. Might be billions?) of volts, and is just an over sized static shock. Currently, I think the largest spark gap we have made caps out at about six feet, and that's a specially made tesla coil pair with lots of volts going through it. Have fun!

Comment: We don't have AC in our city power lines because it's safer (in fact, AC is way more dangerous than DC, since the alternation is what disrupts your heart beat) but because it's is easier to transport over long distances.
Also, if you zap someone with 40000 V they WILL take severe damage (or die). The misconception here is that your voltage stays the same when you load the source, no matter the resistance of the target. The human body has a resistance around 2000 ohm, if you were to put 40000 V across it you would need 20 amps, which would kill you.